# How to get to the parent entity from child entity in grails with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have the following question. In grails, let's say I have the following relationship:

```
class Shop {
    static hasMany = [category: Category]
    String name;
    .... (additional shop attributes)
}

class Category {
    static belongsTo = [Shop]
    static hasMany = [item: Item]
    String name;
    ... (additional category attributes)
}

class Item {
    static belongsTo = [Category]
    String name;
    double price;
    ... (additional item attributes)
}
```

A `Shop` has many different types of categories, such as `Diary`, `Household`, etc. Each category can have multiple items, such as `Milk`, `Cheese`, etc.

They are all unidirectional relationships.

I am using hibernate event listener to capture changes happen after insert/update/delete. It is great if I am only interested in what's happening at each level. For instance, if an item's price is changed, from hibernate event, I can get to the item entity and I will know that the price field is changed with item id xxx.

However, I'd like to associate the changes back to the `Shop` level so I can do some meaningful audit tracing. If I only make the price change for a specific item, I will get a hold of the entity at the item level with the postupdateevent in hibernate. Is there a way to recursively traverse back to the `Shop` level so I can generate a audit trail like `(shopId).category(categoryId).price`? This way, I would know that, for a particular change in a price, it is for which `Category` and for which `Shop`.

Does grail metaclass or hibernate utility class provide such a way to traverse the object tree from the most bottom child to the most top parent?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the bidirectional links then you'll have to "search from the top", probably using criteria

```
def shops = Shop.withCriteria {
  category {
    item {
      idEq(currentItem.id)
    }
  }
}
```

This would give you a List of all the Shops that have a category containing the `currentItem`.

Comment: And if you do have bidirectional links (`static belongsTo = [category:Category]`, `static belongsTo = [shop:Shop]`) you could get your shop from an item using `item.category.shop`. Are there drawbacks for including these links?

Comment: @BobMcCracken it should be safe, but if you have many bidirectional associations you need to be careful about eager vs lazy loading.  If you're not careful a simple query like `Item.findByName("foo")` can end up loading your whole database into memory...